# Is it possible to have a public web server act as proxy to server behind a private network

Tags: web-services, networking

Ok so here is my situation: During the year I live in the dorms and I go back and forth to home and such. I now have enough data that I want to access where ever I am that lugging around a big external hard drive doesn’t seem to cut it. I also want to be able to share much of this content with friends (primarily streaming videos, preferably via a web interface if possible). I've decided that an access anywhere file server would be nice but I don't want to pay it. I have the hardware to setup a file server but my networking situation is a bit tricky. In the dorms and elsewhere I am almost always behind a private network (e.g. 192.168.*.* IP addresses) and/or (generally and) the IP is not static and is instead leased by a DHCP server. This is not amenable to being accessed by anyone. The CS department also gives me small partition on a server that we can host web applications and web pages on. I don't have root on the system, just file rwx rights in my user accounts home directory (and anything below it). So basically, in the dorms I can access a server in the CS department but that server can't access the computer in the dorms unless the computer in the dorms makes contact first (like via SSH).

Is there in way to host files on a computer in the dorms (behind private network and/or dynamic IP) but access them VIA the server in the CS department?

note: I can run demons on the server in the department.

Comment: This is probably not the best way, but you could setup a reverse ssh tunnel to the CS department, then you will be able to ssh from the cs department machine back to your local machine, so you could use that connection (probably with some caching mechanism) with a web server.

Comment: I was wondering if I could do something like that but didn't know the term or quite exactly how it would work. Now the issue is, can I actually transfer files to any client with sftp without first downloading it in full to the department server. I think my partition on the CS department server is like 1.5 GB or something tiny like that so it would have to only store a portion of it at a time (ideally a buffer in memory). Is sftp capable of doing that? If so I think my issues are solved sense I could download any files I wanted and even stream to VLC.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a tunnel it work work similar to a unix pipe, in terms of there only ever being a small buffer of data on the intermediate machine. The transfer will take place entirely in memory on the department server, using none of your disk space and it won't take up much memory either (should be constant for any file size transfer).